# How do i format a java.time.Duration mm:ss

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I have a java.time.Duration and I want to output it in the form of mm:ss. It doesnt seem possible to use DateTimeFormatter since that only accepts LocalTime, ZonedTIme ectera

So I did it like this, works fine for 90 seconds give 1:30, but for 66 seconds gives 1:6 whereas I want 1:06

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(track.getLength().longValue());
System.out.println(duration.toMinutes() + ":" + duration.minusMinutes(duration.toMinutes()).getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could create a `LocalTime` representing the duration from midnight (00:00) and use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
LocalTime t = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plus(duration);
String s = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("m:ss").format(t);
```

Note that this will only work for durations less than one hour.

Comment: If you go beyond 24 hours then this solution will fail.

Comment: @MenoHochschild actually beyond 59:59 minutes. Agreed.

Answer (score 11):

try like this

```
System.out.printf("%d:%02d%n", duration.toMinutes(), duration.minusMinutes(duration.toMinutes()).getSeconds());
```

or

```
    String s = String.format("%d:%02d%n", duration.toMinutes(), duration.minusMinutes(duration.toMinutes()).getSeconds());
```

to format to a String

Comment: Thanks, but the output actually needs to go into  an html file rather than just be output to System.out, doesnt DateTIme offer a solution.

Comment: thanks, thats works but I ve gone for a solution within the datetime ecosphere

Comment: For me a much cleaner solution. The "datetime" ecosphere does not handle formatting of durations.