# Convert current mediaPlayer time to formated time in Android Studio using java

Tags: datetime, time, android-mediaplayer, time-format, current-time

check my function below, its showing like this **124:45** *means it is not converting **hours** into **minutes**. Like this:

[image]

Kindly make changes in my below function that give me correct time.

```
    private String formatedTime(int mCuurentPosition) {
        String totalout="";
        String totalnew="";
        String seconds=String.valueOf(mCuurentPosition % 60);
        String mints =String.valueOf(mCuurentPosition / 60);
        totalout =mints + ":" + seconds;
        totalnew=mints + ":" + "0" + seconds;
        if (seconds.length()==1){
            return totalnew;
        }else {
            return totalout;

        }
```

Comment: Maybe you can piece a solution together from the following existing questions? (1) [Convert number of seconds into HH:MM (without seconds) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096083/convert-number-of-seconds-into-hhmm-without-seconds-in-java) (2) [How can I “pretty print” a Duration in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471397/how-can-i-pretty-print-a-duration-in-java) (3) [How do i format a java.time.Duration mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675095/how-do-i-format-a-java-time-duration-mmss). Search for still more.

Comment: And next time search *before* you post your question, please. It’s easier for you, and it’s easier for us.

Comment: **Finally this function work for me**

`public String formatedTime(int ms){
    String tim = "";
    String secStrng = "";
    String minStrng="";
    int s = (int) (ms % 60);
    int m = (int)(ms /  60) % 60;
    int h = (int)(( ms / (60 * 60)) % 24 );
    if(h > 0){
        tim = h + ":";
    }
    if(s < 10){
        secStrng = "0" + s;
    }else{
        secStrng = "" + s;
    }
    if (m < 10){
        minStrng = "0" + m;
    }else {
        minStrng = "" + m;
    }
    tim = tim + minStrng + ":" + secStrng;
    return tim;
    }`

Comment: Thanks for posting your method. It’s way too much “hand work” for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time.Duration, desugaring and String.format()

```
private String formattedTime(int mCurrentPosition) {
    Duration pos = Duration.ofSeconds(mCurrentPosition);
    long hours = pos.toHours();
    if (hours == 0) {
        return String.format("%d:%02d", pos.toMinutes(), pos.toSecondsPart());
    } else {
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",
                hours, pos.toMinutesPart(), pos.toSecondsPart());
    }
}
```

I haven’t got an Android development environment with me, so am not 100 % sure that desugaring can handle this, but I would certainly dare hope so. The `toMinutesPart` and `toSecondsPart` methods were introduced in Java 9. `String.format()` has been around since Java 1.5, so in any case let it do the formatting for you.

See the above method in action:

```
    System.out.println(formattedTime(47));
    System.out.println(formattedTime(4747));
```

Output is:

> ```
> 0:47
> 1:19:07
> ```

### Question: Doesn’t java.time.Duration require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

Similar questions (no strict duplicates, but loads of helpful information):

- [Convert number of seconds into HH:MM (without seconds) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096083/convert-number-of-seconds-into-hhmm-without-seconds-in-java)
- [How can I “pretty print” a Duration in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471397/how-can-i-pretty-print-a-duration-in-java)
- [How do i format a java.time.Duration mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675095/how-do-i-format-a-java-time-duration-mmss)

Other links:

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: **this work for me**

`public String formatedTime(int ms){
    String tim = "";
    String secStrng = "";
    String minStrng="";
    int s = (int) (ms % 60);
    int m = (int)(ms /  60) % 60;
    int h = (int)(( ms / (60 * 60)) % 24 );
    if(h > 0){
        tim = h + ":";
    }
    if(s < 10){
        secStrng = "0" + s;
    }else{
        secStrng = "" + s;
    }
    if (m < 10){
        minStrng = "0" + m;
    }else {
        minStrng = "" + m;
    }
    tim = tim + minStrng + ":" + secStrng;
    return tim;
    }`

Comment: its show bad here,,because i don't know how to comment properly here,,,but this function work **100% work perfectly** actully i was show media player current time in textview, that time in miliseconds and this function convert miliseconds to Hour:min:sec

if hour not exist then it will show only mintues and seconds, **MUST TRY THIS FUNCTION**

Comment: There is no way to format code in comments here on Stack Overflow. I have pasted your method into my IDE, and it has formatted it for me (don’t expect other readers to do the same).